# Django Rest Framework: How to render data from database with specific object id

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm building a project in Django Rest Framework where users get to see the list of shoes or the detail of the shoe. When I enter the url to list all the shoe it display correctly, when I enter the url with the id of the object, the HTML displays nothing.

[image: No display]

Here is my model

```
class shoes_brand(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Brand'
        verbose_name='Brand'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Brands'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand
class shoe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    foot_size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    quanity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    brand = models.ManyToManyField(shoes_brand)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My view

```
from .models import shoe, shoes_brand
from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class list_object(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'rest/list.html'
    def get(self, request):

        queryset = shoe.objects.all()
        context = {
            'object' : queryset
        }
        print(context)
        return Response(context)

class detail_object(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'rest/detail.html'
    def get(self, request ,pk):
        queryset = shoe.objects.get(pk=pk)
        context = {
        'object' : queryset
        }
        print(context)
        return Response(context)
```

My url

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import list_object, detail_object

app_name = 'shoes_app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('list/', list_object.as_view(), name="List_all"),
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', detail_object.as_view(), name="Detail_object"),
]
```

My serializer

```
class ShoeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = shoe
        fields = '__all__'
class ShoesBrandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = shoes_brand
        fields = '__all__'
```

My template `templates/rest/list.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>All shoes</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for index in object %}
        <li>Shoe: {{ index.name }}</li>
        <li>Foot size: {{ index.foot_size }}</li>
        <li>Price: {{ index.price }}</li>
        <li>Quanity: {{ index.quanity }}</li>
        <li>In-stock: {{ index.available }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

And my template `templates/rest/detail.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Detail/title>
</head>
<body>  
        <li>{{ object.name }}</li>
        <li>{{ object.foot_size }}</li>
        <li>{{ object.price }}</li>
        <li>{{ object.quanity }}</li>
        <li>{{ object.available }}</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be great, thank you

Comment: Just an aside, but your model names are non-standard. They really shoudl be `Shoe` and `ShoeBrand` - not that this is your issue, but having them named like functions or variables makes for confusing code.

Comment: I'm also confused why you are linking `APIView`s to html templates? Usually these would just return a list or a dict? If you want a template use a regular Django View instead ...

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thank you

Comment: I was able to render object id with django rest just some small typo and existing and entering back python environment, and about the ```APIView``` I read the  document on [Renderers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/) and [View](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) because I wanted it to be on custom HTML file